# React Native FlatList, Styled Components and Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components, react-native-flatlist

I have a historic ongoing battle with styled-components , FlatList and typescript ...
Up until now I've been able to make it work with the following :

```
const StyledList = styled(FlatList as new () => FlatList<ItemType>)<CustomProps>(props => ({
  .......
}));
```

This worked fine until I did a recent project upgrade and it's broken this approach.
I now have the following dependency versions:

`"typescript": "~4.3.5"`

`"styled-components": "^5.3.3"`

`"react-native": "0.64.3"`

The errors are like this :

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { ref?: Ref<FlatList< ItemType >> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; } & { theme?: DefaultTheme | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
```

Can anyone offer any insight into this please? What might have changed in recent versions of `styled-components` or `react-native` to prevent the original workaround from working?

Answer (score 6):

```
import { FlatList, FlatListProps } from 'react-native';
    
const List = styled(FlatList as new (props: FlatListProps<ItemType>) => FlatList<ItemType>)``;
```

It works for me.

Comment: I just had to log in to personally thank you! This works like a charm. (react-native: 0.67.3, typescript: 4.4.4, styled-components: 5.3.3).

Comment: Thanks!
After hours of research, found your answer... this works like a charm 

Comment: Any way to make item type generic ?
example:
`export type StyledFlatList<T> = FlatList<T>;
export const StyledFlatList = styled(FlatList as new <T>(props: FlatListProps<T>) => FlatList<T>)` not working as expected..

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but I found a way to make it work with custom props as well as retain original behaviour.

```
type FlatListContainerProps<T> = FlatListProps<T> & {
  $noBorder?: boolean;
};
```

```
const ExtendedFlatList = <T,>({ $noBorder, ...props }: FlatListContainerProps<T>) => {
  return <FlatList {...props} />;
};
```

```
export const FlatListContainer = styled(ExtendedFlatList)<FlatListContainerProps<any>>`
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-width: ${({ $noBorder }: FlatListContainerProps<any>) => ($noBorder ? 0 : "1px")};
  border-color: #f2f2f2;
  background-color: "green";
` as unknown as typeof ExtendedFlatList;
```

I hope this is helpful.